# Crystal reports not working after upgrading .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

i have recently upgrade my project's framework from 3.5 to 4.5. Then i changed application pool version accordingly and now crystal reports are not working. it give no errors but report is blank. it was working fine earlier with .Net CLR version v2. Here i have attached the screenshots of application pool settings and a report i get now

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Which version of crystal report you are using?

AS Crystal 2011 and 2013 do not come with any SDK included in their installs, so you will you have to download and install the latest Crystal for VS software to work with reports in VS 2010 or VS 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5.

Or you will have to install a service pack for Crystal 13. Atleast SP9 is needed to run report in latest framework. Please check link given below -

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: im using crystal reports 2008 version 12.0.0.683 and this is licensed one. can i download that service pack for free from their site? Thanks for your reply

Comment: You will have to read license terms and condition and upgrade crystal report version accordingly. for help check this - [link]https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+2008+(and+9.1,+XI+R1,+XI+R2)+-+Version+and+Download+information+for+Service+Packs

Answer (score 2):

We've had the same problem:

**Cause**: when `.Net` got upgraded to `4.6` on the server the `Crystal Report engine` looked for the folder `../aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_1055` which doesn't exist.  The report page was trying to reference `.js` and `.css` files from the non-existent folder, and the broken `.js` link prevented the page load from completing.

**Solution**: copy folder `../4_0_30319/..` (*or whatever your latest folder is*) and rename to `../4_6_1055/..` (*or your current .Net version*).  The files are unchanged since this is a `.Net` upgrade, not a `Crystal Reports upgrade`.

To check if you have this problem: open developer tools in your browser and look for broken `.js` and `.css` links.